# How to compare 2 vectors element by element using loop

Tags: r, string-matching

I'm trying  to compare elements from 2 vectors in this way,but I get result just for the first element.

```
      >ex1<-c('gdgdg','dd','fffff','ssdsds')

      fuct1<-function(x){
        for(i in 1:length(x)){
          ex2<-c('xxxx','ddd','ddd','ddd','dddd')
          match<-agrep(x[i],ex2[i],value='true')
          return(match[i])
         }
      }

      >fuct1(ex1)
```

By this example I want to compare 'gdgdg' and 'xxxx'(first elements from each vector) 'dd'and 'ddd'(second ones) and so on...,As result I would like to have something as (NA,ddd,NA,NA). My result with my code is just NA.
Thanks for your help.

Comment: +1. I think you need to write TRUE in caps and without quotes, for future reference.

Comment: Why are you assigning a constant value inside your `for loop` -- is that deliberate, a typo, ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

T think you are looking for  `mapply`

```
  mapply(agrep,ex1,ex2,value=TRUE)
```

But this assume that your 2 vectors have the same length.

Answer (score 4):

You want to use `sapply` here:

```
ex2<-c('xxxx','ddd','ddd','ddd','dddd')
sapply(ex1, function(x) agrep(x, ex2))

$gdgdg
integer(0)

$dd
[1] 2 3 4 5

$fffff
integer(0)

$ssdsds
integer(0)
```

Comment: no need for the anonymous function here.  Can simplify to `sapply(ex1, agrep, ex2)`

Comment: In your answer you compare each value in the first with all values in the second vector,but I want to compare in this way: ex1[1] and ex2[1],ex1[2] and ex2[2],ex1[3] and ex2[3]...

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this is what you want:

```
ex1<-c('gdgdg','ddd','fffff','ssdsds')
match<-"TROLOLOL"
fuct1<-function(x){
for(i in 1:length(x)){
ex2<-c('xxxx','ddd','ddd','dddd')
    match<-c(match,agrep(x[i],ex2[i],value=TRUE))
  }
 return(match)
}
fuct1(ex1)[-1]
[1] "ddd"
```

You can complete this if you want NAs I guess :)